# Get average of two consecutive values in a vector depending on logical vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

I am reading data from a file and I am trying to do some manipulation on the vector containing the data basically i want to check if the values come from consecutive lines and if so i want to average each two and put the value in a output vector

part of the data and lines

```
lines=[153 152 153 154 233 233 234 235 280 279 280 281];
Sail=[ 3 4 3 1.5 3 3 1 2 2.5 5 2.5 2 ];
```

here is what i am doing

```
Sail=S(lines);
Y=diff(lines)==1;
for ii=1:length(Y)
   if Y(ii)
      output(ceil(ii/2))=(Sail(ii)+Sail(ii+1))/2; 
   end
end
```

is this correct also is there a way to do that without a for loop

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```
y = find(diff(lines)==1); 
output = mean([Sail(y);Sail(y+1)]);
```

This assumes that when you have, say [233 234 235], you want one value averaging the values from lines [233 234] and one value averaging those from [234 245].  If you wanted to do something more complex when longer sets of consecutive lines exist in your data, then the problem becomes more complex.

Incidentally it's a bad idea to do something like (ceil(ii/2)) - you can't guarantee a unique index for each matching value of `ii`.  If you did want an output the same size as `Sail` (will have zeros in non-matching areas) then you can do something like this:

```
output2 = zeros(size(Sail));
output2(y)=output;
```